# OS X Mountain Lion Apache Forbidden

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, osx-mountain-lion

I follow this guide: [native lamp stack macos x](http://www.astonishdesign.com/blog/native-lamp-stack-mac-os-x)

I created Sites/hello/ folder and htdocs folder in hello. 
When I ping hello.dev -> I see 404
when I try localhost/~username/hello -> Forbidden
localhost/hello -> Forbidden

I don't know how can I ready webserver.

Comment: You get an HTTTP 404 error when *pinging*? Really?

Comment: No I wrote it wrong. My output was 'ping: cannot resolve project.dev: Unknown host' when I ping hello.dev but I fix it. It was related to configure DNS servers. But again, when I hello.dev/ on my browser, I see '403. Forbidden. You don't have permission to access / on this server.' I think it is related to /Users/myusername/Sites permission but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Did accessing `http://localhost/~username` work before you changed your Apache configuration? What are its permissions? Have you tried making it world-readable? I.e. `chmod -Rv a+rx ~/Sites`?

Answer (score 0):

- Uncomment `#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`
- Add `127.0.0.1 test.dev` to `/etc/hosts`
- Save this as `/etc/apache2/users/username.conf`:

  ```
  <Directory "/Users/username/Sites">
      Options Indexes MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </Directory>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName test.dev
      DocumentRoot /Users/username/Sites/test
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName localhost
      DocumentRoot /Users/username/Sites
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Run `sudo apachectl restart`